# Black Screen When Using NoMachine (Server is using FreeNX) Failed Gnome Session?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, freenx, remote-x-session

I was following instructions from here:
http://www.drivard.com/2012/06/installation-freenx-server-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise/

I installed FreeNX on my server (Ubuntu 14.04).

I am able to remotely ssh into the server.

Using NoMachine (which has been tested with other servers and work on the client) I was able to connect to the server BUT THE SCREEN WAS BLACK.

The process for connecting to the server is:

- set up the connection (via ssh using the 'NoMachine login' option).
- connect, entering password and username
- chose 'start Gnome session'
- Then black screen.

I have successfully managed this process at other times.

Edit:

- resetting the server doesn't help
- the problem persists when using different NoMachine clients

Comment: I have seen a lot of online advice about editing files in a /NX director or ~/.NX or /usr/NX, I have none of these directories. I believe because I am using FreeNX.

Comment: Is it reproducible? Did you try rebooting the remote server?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov I did reboot the remote server. Still black screen. The screen is black across diff NoMachine clients as well.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution allows me to log in via NoMachine but I'm still unable to disconnect from a session without terminating it.

On the server I executed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Then on the client when setting up nomachine client I selected "custom" instead of gnome session and entered the following options:

```
Desktop: Custom
Run the following command: /usr/bin/startxfce4
Options: New virtual desktop
```

I followed instructions from [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2180353&page=2)